# jQuery ID Number Range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery script that will add a class to list items within a certain ID range. I use numbers in my ID's and want to adjust a range of ID's.

```
<li id="item-15">Something</li>
<li id="item-16">Something</li>
<li id="item-17">Something</li>
<li id="item-18">Something</li>
<li id="item-19">Something</li>
```

I want to add a class to say items 16 through 19. How would I do this?

```
jQuery('li#item-[16-19]).addClass('the-class');
```

I am not really sure how to do it. Maybe `.each()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what the jquery [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)
method was designed for.

> Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the .slice()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object
>   from a subset of the matching
>   elements. The supplied start index
>   identifies the position of one of the
>   elements in the set; if end is
>   omitted, all elements after this one
>   will be included in the result.

so

```
jQuery('li').slice(17,21).addClass('the-class');
//note Zero Based indexing. Plus it wont include the last element.
```

live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/VpNnJ/

you could also combine the :gt() and :lt() selectors as follows

`$('li:gt(16):lt(19)').addClass('the-class');`

again a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLjXE/

Answer (score 9):

```
var min = 16, max = 19;

$('li[id^=item-]').addClass(function ()
{
    var i = parseInt(this.id.replace('item-', ''), 10);
    if (i >= min && i <= max) return 'the-class';
});
```

For the sake of specificity, you should probably qualify the selector with a common parent, such as

```
$('#some-ul-id > li[id^=item-]').addClass(...);
```

If the IDs are always sequentially increasing, and zero-indexed, you can simplify:

```
$('#some-ul-id > li[id^=item-]').addClass(function (i)
{
    if (i >= min && i <= max) return 'the-class';
});
```

or, as [@matchew suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247354/jquery-id-number-range/6247399#6247399), use `.slice()`:

```
$('#some-ul-id > li[id^=item-]').slice(min, max).addClass('the-class');
```

Comment: returning the favor, but your examples seem needless complicated =)

Comment: Great list of answers. +1, but I have to give it to @matchew for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('li[id^="item-"]').filter(function() {
    var number = this.id.replace(/\D+/, '');
    return number >= 16 && number <= 19
}).addClass('the-class');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/psjnB/).

Answer (score 0):

(Just an alternate answer)
Go for custom jQuery Selectors.

In your case it 'could' be:

```
$.expr[':'].customId = function(obj){
  var $this = $(obj);
  var id = $this.attr('id');
  var number = id.replace(/\D+/, '');
  if ((new RegExp(/^item-/).test(id)) && (number > 15 && number < 20)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

// Usage:
$('a:customId').addClass('the-class');
```

Reference:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1457-How-To-Build-A-Custom-jQuery-Selector.htm